# PHP AJAX POST request returns error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using PHP to process an AJAX POST request from a form, and need it to send a JSON object back. My php code.

```
<?php

function main(){
$a = $_POST['args'];
$myFile = "jsonargs.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $a);
fwrite($fh, "\n");
fwrite($fh, "-o ./json\n");
fwrite($fh, "-j\n");
fclose($fh);
$output = shell_exec('command 2>&1; ./syn-bin/synoptic-jar.sh -c jsonargs.txt ' . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$json = file_get_contents('./json.json');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

}

main();

?>
```

However, when I make the ajax call with jquery's ajax form plugin, my error function is called. If I submit it as a normal form instead of making an ajax call, it works correctly.  How do I properly return a JSON object?

My AJAX request:

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
    error: showResponse
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 

// pre-submit callback 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 

alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 

return true; 
} 

// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 


alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
    '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
    console.log(responseText);
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow's syntax highlighting shows that you clearly have an issue with double-quotes somewhere...

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake indenting the code. It should be fixed now.

Comment: maybe check the console to see what error you are getting from the server?

Comment: Monkey is pointing out this:  $_FILES["file" ["tmp_name"] - should be  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]

Comment: @VolkanUlukut baby steps, just baby steps for now

Comment: you seem to try to upload files using AJAX. this is not supported like normal form posts. you need to use a different approach. are you familiar with that? or maybe you could also post your ajax request so we could skip guessing.

Comment: what is alerted once you make the ajax call?

Comment: what do you mean? I call alert() to display a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

After research, my problem was that I can't upload a file with AJAX. I had to use a hidden iframe to fix the problem.